# My little,small program has problems (Ubuntu 14.04, Qt5, Code::Blocks)

Tags: qt5, codeblocks, ubuntu-14.04

Ok i am going to post a series of pictures i took, with some red annotations on them:

Picture 1 : My Main.cpp

[image: My Main.cpp]

Picture 2 :  Qt5.3 Directory on Ubuntu

[image: Qt5.3 Directory on Ubuntu]

Picture 3 : Additional include directories on Code::Blocks

[image: Additional include directories on Code::Blocks]

Picture 4 :  Linker Directory i’ve included on Code::Blocks

[image: Linker Directory i’ve included on Code::Blocks]

Picture 5 :  Linker Libraries i point to

[image: Linker Libraries i point to]

Picture 6 : Some other options

[image: Some other options]

Picture 7 : And the error i am getting when i finally run the program

[image: the error i am getting when i finally run the program]

This is the first time i’am trying to go into Qt5 on Ubuntu and i need to work with Code::Blocks,
because this is the IDE i am most confordable with in case someone suggest QtCreator. I know its 
powerfull but i will use Qt5 only for some parts, not the whole project will be based on Qt5. Is there any good
tutorial-introduction you know about Qt5 and Linux in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on error message I believe that source of the error is linker settings which miss `Qt5Widget` library.

Comment: That was it. I feel dump.